# is it possible to use sqlmetal in sqlite

Tags: windows-phone-7

Hello friends I want to develop database application in windows phone using sqlite.I just want to know whether **sqlmetal** can be used  in **wp7** and also want to know does it supports **.net v4.0** or any alternative solution is there. When I googled I came across using **dblinq** in **sqlite**. Please provide some sample for this.

Comment: Well u can't use sqlMetal in WP7. and WP7 apps are in silverlight and it almost supports .Net4 and 4.5 classes for various tasks. Till now dbLinq is for desktop versions only. For WP7 Sqlite, u can get help from here -- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/151179/SQLite-on-WP7